# What's wrong with my arugula - yellow/pink leaves

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, herbs

I planted my arugula roughly 6 weeks ago and the small plants were growing very nice and fast. During the last weeks, however, their leaves turned yellow/pink with white spots (maybe mold?) on them. They are growing inside, in front of an East-facing window.

What is this caused by?

- Too much sunlight?
- Too much water? Too little water?

[image: arugula photo]
[image: arugula photo]
[image: arugula photo]
[image: arugula photo]

Comment: Looks crowded. Too much light for an Italian green? No.

Comment: Got it, will plant less into the next batch. Could be too much or too little water?